# JQuery mobile swipe to change pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, jquery-mobile

For the life of me I cannot figure out why I'm not able to change pages in my JQuery mobile document when I swipe right. I know the swipe event is written correctly because when I swap it out with and `alert("test");`that fires correctly.

Heres what I have done :

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('.table').on('swiperight', function(){
     $.mobile.changePage("#home");
   });
});

</script>
```

I've referred to the JQuery mobile documentation and to other posts here on the forum but have not been able to resolve this issue. Any ideas?

Heres a fiddle of the project. http://jsfiddle.net/a6TZW/

Comment: Can we see your HTML? We're going to need more than this to help you.

Comment: maybe you could paste the html for the #home

Comment: try this `$(document).on('swiperight','.table', function(){
     $.mobile.changePage("#home");
   });` without putting it inside a `$function()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to wrap this event within `$function()` as such events are triggered once they occur.

**Swipe events:**

```
$(document).on('swiperight','.table', function()
  { $.mobile.changePage("#page2"); 
 });

$(document).on('swipeleft','.table', function()
  { $.mobile.changePage("#page1"); 
 });
```

Also, you can combine them this way:

```
$(document).on('swiperight swipeleft','.table', function(event) {
 if (event.type == 'swiperight') {
  $.mobile.changePage("#page2");
 }
 if (event.type == 'swipeleft') {
  $.mobile.changePage("#page1");
 }
});
```

JSfiddle: [Test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/FwwkT/)

Comment: Alright, I'm pretty sure that Jquery is messing with me because, when I use the script that you have provided but use an alert instead of a changePage, it works. For some reason I cannot execute a changePage.